Best way to show or hide a image CollectionView .NET MAUI?
I tried to show or hide an image using the IsVisible property based on whether the ImageSource is empty or not but this caused the Collection View to look laggy when scrolling and sometimes show images on items it shouldn't.
My quick fix was to copy the entire control but without the image and use a DataTemplateSelector and it worked fine but my concern is that I basically have two identical codes to show or not the image.
Is there a way to do it better? while still maintaining efficiency and functionality? Thanks.

please read [ask] before posting.  You need to include the relevant code if you expect us to help you

Seems DataTemplateSelector solved your question?  It is used to choose a DataTemplate at runtime based on the value of a data-bound property.  Though it has some limitations
